# IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL: java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a WCF 4.0 service for internal use. Another team is trying to consume it in Java.

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: 
ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "PasswordReuseFaultFault" ...
```

One source suggests it may be a [Soap 1.1 vs. Soap 1.2 issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/thread/7e73e1a2-2d06-4065-bc51-011d35553e61)

Indeed my WCF generated WSDL

```
<wsdl:fault name="PasswordReuseFaultFault"> 
  <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#blah_blah_blah_PasswordReuseFaultFault_Fault"/> 
  <soap12:fault name="PasswordReuseFaultFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
```

notice the `<soap12:fault>`instead of the expected `<soap:fault>`  I'm pretty sure that is the cause of the problem.

- How do I get WCF to generate soap 1.1 WSDL ?

**or**

- What should I tell the Java team to do so their tools can understand the newer protocol?

---

Edit:

I found out that basicHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.1 and puts the expected `<soap:fault>`
in the WSDL, where wsHttpBinding puts `<soap12:fault>` (using the SOAP 1.2 spec I guess.)

I found [some suggestions](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=49466) that [using Axis instead of the IDE tool](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/ant/axis-wsdl2java.html) will yield better results, I'm not sure if I can get the Java team to buy into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have discovered that **AXIS2** will work just fine with the  tags.  [AXIS2 requires very minimal additional set-up to the eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html).    I will try to get the java guys to utilize that.

Here is a good explanation of [making both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 available for a WCF service](http://blog.allanglen.com/2010/04/wcf-interoperability-with-soap-1-1-and-soap-1-2-clients).